# How to plot several animations from a parametric plot loop

Tags: plotting, animation, parametric-functions

I have a piece of code which plots parametric functions using for loops.

```
a = {6, 2}
b = {2, 6}
c = {-1, -2}
func = {}
For[i = 1, i <= 2, i++, 
plot = ParametricPlot3D[{a [[i]] Cos[t] - c[[i]], b [[i]] Sin[t], 
0}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> 7];
AppendTo[func, plot]]

Show[func]
```

This plots the following paths[image]

if i animate them using the following code:

```
a = {6, 1}
b = {2, 1}
c = {-1, -2}
func = {}
For[i = 1, i <= 2, i++, 
plot = ParametricPlot3D[{a[[i]] Cos[t] - c[[i]], b[[i]]Sin[t], 
0}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> 7];
AppendTo[func, plot]]

Animate[Show[func, 
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Red, 
  Point[Dynamic[{a [[1]] Cos[t] - c[[1]], b[[1]] Sin[t], 0}]]}]
  ] , {t, 0, 10}]
```

I only get one point travelling around the elliptical path.

However,if i replace values of a[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYAgE.jpg)],b[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYAgE.jpg)],c[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYAgE.jpg)] with i, as per the loop

```
Animate[Show[func, 
      Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Red, 
      Point[Dynamic[{a [[i]] Cos[t] - c[[i]], b[[i]] Sin[t], 0}]]}]
      ] , {t, 0, 10}]
```

i get this plot[image]
and this error message: "Coordinate {-Part[{-1., -2.}, 3] - 0.9974703237996385 Part[{6., 1.}, 3], (-0.07108412719478453) Part[{2., 1.}, 3], 0.} should be a triple of numbers, or a Scaled form."

Is it possible to animate points travelling around their individual parametric paths within the same plot?

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {6, 1}
b = {2, 1}
c = {-1, -2}
func = {}
For[i = 1, i <= 2, i++, 
 plot = ParametricPlot3D[{a[[i]] Cos[t] - c[[i]], b[[i]] Sin[t], 
    0}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> 7];
 AppendTo[func, plot]]

Animate[Show[func, 
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Red, 
    Point[Table[{a[[i]] Cos[t] - c[[i]], b[[i]] Sin[t], 0}, {i, 1, 
       2}]]}]], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Note :
- in your code, `Dynamic` is useless
- it is recommended not to use `For[...]`. Hence I use `Table[...]` in my mofiication of your code.

By the way, your code :

```
func = {}
For[i = 1, i <= 2, i++, 
 plot = ParametricPlot3D[{a[[i]] Cos[t] - c[[i]], b[[i]] Sin[t], 
    0}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> 7];
 AppendTo[func, plot]]
```

could be rewritten like this :

```
func = Table[
  ParametricPlot3D[{a[[i]] Cos[t] - c[[i]], b[[i]] Sin[t], 0}, {t, 0, 
    2 Pi}, PlotRange -> 7], {i, 1, 2}]
```

Comment: Thanks for help, is there way to alter the framerate of the animation so that that it runs smoother? I have ~2000 objects that have been rotated by  Euler rotation matrix and when I run the animation, its very slow